# Umbraco dynamic "Where" filter returns either IQueryable or DynamicPublishedContentList inconsistently

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco

I am trying to create a multilevel dropdown menu in Umbraco using a recursive helper and for some reason I am getting a compilation error saying that I am passing a wrong argument when I pass the children of the root elements to the helper.

I have found some solutions but they don't use a helper so I don't know if the problem is the helper or I am doing something wrong.

My code is:

```
 @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
 @{ var selection = CurrentPage.Site().Children.Where("Visible"); }
 <div class="fleft menu_area">
     <button class="btn btn-primary visible-xs" type="button" data-     toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-   controls="mainMenu"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></i> Menu </button>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainMenu">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             @CreateListItems(selection)
         </ul>
     </div>
 </div>

 @helper CreateListItems(Umbraco.Web.Models.DynamicPublishedContentList  collection)
 {
     foreach (var item in collection)
     {
         if (item.Children.Where("Visible").Count() > 0)
         {
             <li class="menuOption dropdown  @(item.IsAncestorOrSelf(CurrentPage) ? "current" : null)" data-menu- id="@item.GetPropertyValue("menuOptionIdentifier")">
                 <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                     @{            
                    CreateListItems(item.Children.Where("Visible")); // THE PROBLEM IS HERE
                     }
                 </ul>
           </li>
          }
         else
         {
             <li class="@(item.IsAncestorOrSelf(CurrentPage) ? "current" : null)"><a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a></li>
         }
     }
 }
```

I have seen that `item.Children.Where("Visible")` is returning an iQueryable so I tried to assign it to a variable and that variable was the right DynamicPublishedContentList type. I passed that variable to the helper but I got the same error.

I have tried another version using foreachs outside the helper and instead passing DynamicPublishedContentList I passed DynamicPublishedContent item but I couldn't make it work either, I got the same error.

I tried casting the Where result to a List but I got an error as well saying that a can't do that from an IQueryable `does not contain a definition for 'ToList'`

What is the right way of passing those children?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. The problem is that you are trying to pass an `IQueryable` into the `DynamicPublishedContentList`. I'd just switch it all to dynamics, so you don't have to worry about specifically what is being passed around. If you are going to go with dynamics, you might as well avoid having to deal with all of the type conversions.

The reason you are getting mixed messages from the calls to `Where("Visible")` is that `dynamic` isn't just a regular type. It basically flags the compiler to skip all of the type checking, so it happens at runtime. This means that at runtime, your dynamics will compile to objects.

It turns out that when you call `.Where("Visible")` from explicit `DynamicPublishedContentList`, the `.Where("Visible")` method in the `Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentExtensions` is called. However, extension methods don't work with dynamics because the C# RuntimeBinder doesn't give you access to the extension methods. When we call `.Where("Visible")` on a `CurrentPage.Site().Children`, it doesn't see the extension methods, and the `TryInvokeMember` method overridden on the `DynamicPublishedContentList` class is called.

This is probably your most simple solution:

```
@helper CreateListItems(Umbraco.Web.Models.DynamicPublishedContentList  collection)
```

to

```
@helper CreateListItems(dynamic collection)
```

Alternatively, you could use the more strongly typed IPublishedContent. I like this because the extra intellisense helps a lot.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    var root = Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf(1);
    var selection = root.Children.Where(n => !n.GetPropertyValue<bool>("umbracoNaviHide")).ToList();
}

<div class="fleft menu_area">
    <button class="btn btn-primary visible-xs" type="button" data-     toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-   controls="mainMenu"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></i> Menu </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainMenu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            @CreateListItems(selection)
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

@helper CreateListItems(List<IPublishedContent> collection)
{
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        if (item.Children.Any(n => !n.GetPropertyValue<bool>("umbracoNaviHide")))
        {
            <li class="menuOption dropdown  @(item.IsAncestorOrSelf(Model.Content) ? "current" : null)" data-menu- id="@item.GetPropertyValue("menuOptionIdentifier")">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    @CreateListItems(item.Children.Where(n => !n.GetPropertyValue<bool>("umbracoNaviHide")).ToList())
                </ul>
            </li>
        }
        else
        {
            <li class="@(item.IsAncestorOrSelf(Model.Content) ? "current" : null)"><a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a></li>
        }
    }
}
```

You can get the current page as an IPublishedContent with `Model.Content`.

Comment: Fantastic! that worked but... why the other solutions didn't? I still don't get it. If CurrentPage.Site().Children.Where("Visible"); is passing a DynamicPublishedContentList  to the helper instead a iQueryable why is item.Children.Where("Visible") returning something different?

Comment: Thank for asking. Sorry I didn't go into that the first time around. I've updated my answer with more details.